# How can we update XML caption attribute value with a new one using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to update the caption value of this XML using XSLT. Is there any way to do it?

**Background:**
I have many XMLs and I need to update all XML's caption's value with a new one. So that can be achieved via code i.e. looping through each node and update. But I am looking if we do have any way that can use XSLT to update it.

Below is the sample XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Form TableName="ABC" Name="A" ModuleID="1" PrimaryKeyName="ID" Header="Viewer Mapping" FormVersion="1.0">
    <Section Name="1" Attributes="display:none" Caption="**OldCaptionValue1**">
        <Control Name="ID" Caption="**OldCaptionValue2**" DBType="Int Identity(1,1)" PrimaryKey="true" Type="Hidden" Value="{_REQUEST:InstanceID}" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="SectionMessage" Caption="**OldCaptionValue3**">
        <Control Name="Note" Caption="**OldCaptionValue4**" Width="500px" Type="Display" Attributes="color:red;margin-bottom:10px;" Value="Refrain making changes.." />
    </Section>
</Form>
```

OutputXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Form TableName="ABC" Name="A" ModuleID="1" PrimaryKeyName="ID" Header="Viewer Mapping" FormVersion="1.0">
    <Section Name="Section000" Attributes="display:none" Caption="**NewCaptionValue1**">
        <Control Name="ID" Caption="**NewCaptionValue2**" DBType="Int Identity(1,1)" PrimaryKey="true" Type="Hidden" Value="{_REQUEST:InstanceID}" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="SectionMessage" Caption="**NewCaptionValue3**">
        <Control Name="Note" Caption="**NewCaptionValue4**" Width="500px" Type="Display" Attributes="color:red;margin-bottom:10px;" Value="Refrain making changes.." />
    </Section>
</Form>
```

Comment: Example output would be helpful, or at least an indication if you are looking to change any/all `@Caption` to the same value. The `Section/@Caption` have one value and the `Control/@Caption` have different values "ID" and "". Which @Caption are you looking to change?

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: @MadsHansen 
Above XML example contains old caption values as OldCaptionValue1,OldCaptionValue2, OldCaptionValue3 & OldCaptionValue4. That I need to replace with NewCaptionValue1, NewCaptionValue2, NewCaptionValue3 & NewCaptionValue4 respectively.

Hope that answers your question

Comment: @ravishkumar I am afraid it does not answer the question at all. How is the stylesheet supposed to know which old value to replace with which new value? Where are the new values coming from? Please explain the required logic in simple terms. How would you do this manually?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this approach will work

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Section/@Caption">
    <xsl:param name="sectionOldValue" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="sectionCaption" select="concat('SomeSectionNewValue_', $sectionOldValue)"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="Caption">
        <xsl:value-of select="$sectionCaption"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Control/@Caption">
    <xsl:param name="controlOldValue" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="controlCaption" select="concat('SomeControlNewValue_', $controlOldValue)"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="Caption">
        <xsl:value-of select="$controlCaption"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```